# Why won't the last else statement work? Python

Tags: python

Saying "n" to "Do you have a fever?" outputs False instead of prompting me for an answer to "Do you have a stuffy nose?". The other else statements work. Saying "y" to "Do you have a fever?", "n" to "Do you have a rash?", and "n" to "Does your ear hurt?" prints "Flu". I can't figure out why that one else statement doesn't work.

```
def part3():
    if(raw_input("Do you have a fever? (y/n): ") == "y"):
        if(raw_input("Do you have a rash? (y/n): ") == "y"):
            print "Measles"
        else:
            if(raw_input("Does your ear hurt? (y/n): ") == "y"):
                print "Ear Infection"
            else:
                print "Flu" 
    else:
        if(raw_input("Do you have a stuffy nose? (y/n): " == "y")):
            print "Head Cold"
        else:
            print "Hypochondriac"
```

Comment: Variables exist for a reason... Just an FYI... It let's you break down code and then do small, easily legible tasks that prevent errors like this.

Comment: [`elif`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) is a thing btw

Comment: @Huey why elif when there are only two options?

Comment: You have an else: hypochondriac.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh I'm never reusing the variables though

Comment: @Huey no, i meant that the there is only a "y" or a "n"

Comment: I mean `if (raw_input..)`, `elif(raw_input...)`, then `else: hypochondriac`. But it's not a big deal.

Comment: @user2149780, you should really read Python's style guide recommendations.
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations

You're failing on both the compound statement and have unnecessarily long lines. Python emphasis *readability*. Choosing to arbitrarily not use variables and combine statements on a few lines is not considered good code, and caused this error.

Comment: @Huey oh i see them... how do you catch those? it takes me a while to find them

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh all the cool kids do it this way though :( by unnecessarily long lines, do you mean the things inside the if statements?

Comment: Technically, you're not in strict violation of long lines (but you are pragmatically).

All the "cool kids", by that, you mean, people who don't code Python?
And yeah. You're getting user input, defining a "yes" condition, doing a comparison, and then evaluating the comparison with an if clause on the same line.
Something like this, where the user input is then separated from the comparison, is a lot more readable and therefore, when your code gets more complex, easier to debug.
http://pastebin.com/PDtu6DFY

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found your mistake, and you are gonna hate yourself for it. This line

```
if(raw_input("Do you have a stuffy nose? (y/n): " == "y")):
```

should be

```
if(raw_input("Do you have a stuffy nose? (y/n): ") == "y"):
```

To explain a little more about why it printed false:
    "Do you have a stuffy nose? (y/n): " == "y" 
is evaluated to False, so it is like saying
    raw_input(False)
which will print "False", but still get input

Comment: I'm so glad. I thought it was an obscure Python thing that I didn't know about. Phew.